# Vectorization of conditional distributions for pairs columns in a matrix

Tags: r, vectorization

Given two vectors of integers:

```
X <- c(0, 201, 0, 0, 160, 0, 0, 0, 15, 80)
Y <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 4, 42, 10, 19, 0)
```

I want to calculate the probability p1 = P(X10 > X11), where X10 is a variable with a conditional distribution of X given that Y = 0, and X11 is a variable with a conditional distribution of X given that Y > 0. (This problem is motivated by a desire to implement equation 8 from RS Pimentel et al. 2015, Stat Prob Lett 96:61-67.)

For two pairs of vectors, I can simply calculate:

```
N <- length(X)
X10 <- X
X10[Y > 0] <- 0
X11 <- X
X11[Y == 0] <- 0
p1 <- sum(X10 > X11) / N
```

However, I now want to calculate p1 for all pairs of columns in an integer matrix:

```
Z <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 8, 0)
matrix(c(X, Y, Z), ncol = 3)
```

I am not interested in the diagonal.

The desired output is therefore:

```
      [,1] [,2]  [,3] 
[1,]       0.2   0.3
[2,]             0.2
[3,]
```

How can I write a function that will calculate p1 for all pairs of columns in the matrix?

Comment: You may try with `combn` on each pair of columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom function to compute your probability, then apply it to each combination of columns:

```
p1 <- function(x, y) {
  x10 <- x
  x10[y > 0] <- 0
  x11 <- x
  x11[y == 0] <- 0
  mean(x10 > x11)
}

combinations <- t(combn(ncol(M), 2))

# create a matrix of NAs, fill the appropriate values
result <- matrix(NA, nrow = ncol(M), ncol = ncol(M))

result[combinations] <- apply(combinations, 1, function(r) p1(M[, r[1]], M[, r[2]]))
```